# Manim MathTex - Multiple text fragments in numerator of fraction

Tags: python, latex, manim

I am working on a Manim project where I am manipulating equations algebraically. This is made easy using many of the provided utilities, but in order to do so smoothly I must separate `MathTex` objects into multiple isolated "fragments". This can be done in many ways, but I have opted to use the double brace syntax:

```py
MathTex("{{a}} + {{b}}").submobjects
# [SingleStringMathTex('a'), SingleStringMathTex(' + '), SingleStringMathTex('b')]
```

This works for most math equations, including those which have a fragment in the denominator of a fraction

```py
MathTex("\\frac{ a }{ {{b}} }}").submobjects
# [SingleStringMathTex('\\frac{ a }{ '), SingleStringMathTex('b'), SingleStringMathTex(' }}')]
```

However, no matter which method I use it seems as though I am not able to create a fragment within the numerator.

```py
MathTex("\\frac{ {{a}} }{ {{b}} }}").submobjects
# ERROR    LaTeX compilation error: Missing }       tex_file_writing.py:265
#          inserted.
```

This seems to be a limitation imposed by the LaTeX compilation and not Manim's fragment system. I am looking for any workarounds that will allow me to create a Manim fragment in the numerator of a fraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Manim CE examples also mention another method for complex strings when isolating sub-strings do not work. It involves considering manual indices of the individual substrings and setting the colour on the substring indices directly.

So, for the Tex code `\frac{a}{b}`, it would probably look a bit like this:

```
text = MathTex(r"\frac{a}{b}", font_size=24)
self.add(index_labels(text[0]))
text[0][0:1].set_color(YELLOW)
text[0][1:2].set_color(RED)
self.add(text)
```

I would verify and tell you if it worked, but I use ManimGL so MathTex isn't compatible on my installation of Manim.

Comment: Thank you! This is an effective method for setting color or doing formatting, but since my intention was to use the `TransformMatchingTex` function it does not work for my purposes. I am going to mark this as the accepted answer, but see my answer for an additional workaround.

Comment: Nice! Yeah, I generally had a lot of problems dealing with LaTeX _frac_'s as well, and apparently really specific design choices involving _frac_'s end up with a failure to segment the numerator and denominator. Thanks for posting your workaround too!

Comment: Is it possible to maybe use `ReplacementTransform` to swap out individual sub-mobjects of `Tex`?

Answer (score 1):

This breaks because the `frac` command in *LaTeX* requires multiple arguments, and does not compile when only one is given. This is an issue that could potentially require attention in the Manim source, but for my case, I was able to use the alternative notation for fractions in *LaTeX*.

```py
MathTex("{ {{a}} \\over { {{b}} } }").submobjects
# [SingleStringMathTex('{ '), SingleStringMathTex('a'), SingleStringMathTex(' \\over { '), SingleStringMathTex('b'), SingleStringMathTex(' } }')]
```